# UseEffect doesn't run again when I click back on browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I have product page with a row of shoe brand logos like Nike, Adidas, etc..and below the row are images of all our shoe inventory.  When the user clicks on a brand, for example nike, the url changes to /nike and filters the images to show just nike shoes.  Then if I click Adidas, url changes to /adidas and filters to show only adidas shoes.  However, when I the back button on the browser, the URL will change back to /nike but the images remain adidas.  I have useEffect to run on any change to the brandId which is the prop that is used to filter the shoes.

Here's my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import "../styles/ShoesPage.css"
import "../styles/Players.css"
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import Axios from 'axios'


export default props => {
    const brandId = props.match.params.brand
    const [shoes, setShoes] = useState([])

    useEffect(() =>{

        Axios.get(`/shoes/brands/+${brandId}`).then(res=>
            setShoes(res.data)
        )

    }, [brandId])

    return (
        <>


        <div id="playercontainer">
            {shoes.map((shoe, i) => (
                <Link to={"/product/" + shoe.id} key={'shoe' + i}>
                    <div className="player">
                        <img className="shoeImg" src={`${shoe.pic}`} alt="" />
                        <div className="playerDesc">
                            <div className="teamName">{shoe.brand}</div>
                            <div className="playerName">{shoe.shoe}</div>   
                            <div className="shoePrice">${shoe.price}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </Link>
            ))}

        </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Does the `brandId` change?

Comment: Yes, the brandId is passed through from in params from the route.  The route is shoes/:brand and brandId is const brandId = props.match.params.brand....I thought the brandId would dynamically change as the url changed.